# Mssql The repetition value of the 2 tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select

I want write query to do below result but my query doesn't work.

---

```
    Table A

    code    |    date
    -------------------------------------
    3            2015-01-26

    4            2015-01-27

    5            2015-01-27

    6            2015-01-26

    8            2015-01-26
```

---

```
Table B

code    |    Code B
-------------------------------------
3            12

3            10

5             3

6            10

6            12

8            12
```

---

```
Results

code B    |    value_Repetition 
-------------------------------------
12                   3

10                   2

3                     1
```

---

My query

```
DECLARE @ddd int

select @ddd = code FROM Table A where date between '2015-01-01' and '2015-01-27'

SELECT       code B ,COUNT(code B) AS value_Repetition 
    FROM     Table B
    where code = @ddd
    GROUP BY code B
    ORDER BY value_Repetition  DESC
```

Comment: i didn't get any error , query result is not complete
just show last code B from table B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it.

```
CREATE TABLE TableA(
    Code    INT,
    [Date]  DATE
)
CREATE TABLE TableB(
    Code    INT,
    CodeB   INT
)
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES
(3, '2015-01-26'), (4, '2015-01-27'), (5, '2015-01-27'),
(6, '2015-01-26'), (8, '2015-01-26');
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES
(3, 12), (3, 10), (5, 3),
(6, 10), (6, 12), (8, 12);

SELECT
    b.CodeB,
    COUNT(b.CodeB) AS Value_Repetition
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b
    ON a.Code = b.Code
WHERE
    a.[Date] BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-27'
GROUP BY
    b.CodeB
ORDER BY
    COUNT(b.CodeB) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mentioning the column alias `COUNT(code B)` inside your count function..
Try this..

```
DECLARE @ddd int

select @ddd = code FROM Table A where date between '2015-01-01' and '2015-01-27'

SELECT       code B ,COUNT(code) AS value_Repetition 
    FROM     Table B
    where code = @ddd
    GROUP BY code
    ORDER BY value_Repetition  DESC
```

Comment: Hi , your query Results :

code B    |    value_Repetition 
-------------------------------------
12                   1

Comment: Try the updated query.. The group by also had the alias